# ¿Cómo hacer que en un procedimiento almacenado envíe un mensaje indicando que la clave primaria ya existe?

Tags: sql

```
create or replace procedure AgregarCiudad(pais VARCHAR2,
                                          nombre VARCHAR2,
                                          Region number)
is
begin
    insert into PAISES values (pais,nombre,Region);
end;
```

ese es el código y no se como hacer para que al ingresar la misma primary key me mande un mesaje diciendo que la llave primaria ya fue ingresada

Comment: Deberias aclarar a que base de datos te refieres y como ejecutas ese codigo. Lo mas probable es que lo q pedis no se pueda hacer, pero seguro hay variantes

Comment: @gbianchi creo que puso la etiqueta de sql.

Comment: Sql no es ninguna base en particular. Es el lenguaje q usan la mayoria de las bases, por eso le pregunte todo eso @FranciscoNúñez

Comment: bueno ya yo deje mi respuesta par sql

Comment: tu respuesta es para sql server.. por favor aclara eso en la respuesta.. Vuelvo a insistir (y esta en la descripcion de la etiqueta), SQL es un lenguaje.. no una base de datos... Pero si a OP le sirve, bienvenido sea.. solo habra que agregar esa etiqueta a la pregunta @FranciscoNúñez

Comment: Por lo de VARCHAR2 me parece que es Oracle o DB2..